# Passive builds when uploading with Xcode Cloud

Tags: xcode, cloud, app-store-connect

I have uploaded new builds with xcode cloud. I tested it successfully. Now I want to send this build to App Store submit. But this build seems passive. Any suggestions are welcome.

It looks as expected when I upload the same build manually from xcode.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.